# Web3.py filter.get_new_entries() returns nothing if over 10 events have been emitted?

Tags: events, web3.py, python

I'm using the following loop to try and add the metadata for tokens generated in my own smart contract, it all works exactly as intended when I am generating up to 9 "bots" at a time, but as soon as it's 10 or more, it doesn't seem to fire at all? Any idea as to why this could be? I know for a fact that the events are being emitted as I can see that in the smart contract.

Also, is this the best way to do this? Will this work with a real Ethereum infura node? Thanks a bunch!

```
def log_loop(newBot_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in newBot_filter.get_new_entries():
            bot = event['args']
            print(bot)
            dbh.add_bot(bot['_id'], ...)
        time.sleep(poll_interval)

newBot_filter = contract.events.NewBot.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
Thread(target=log_loop, args=(newBot_filter, 2)).start()
```

Comment: Still not sure what's causing this but I optimized my contract and now I can do at least 15 without any problems (haven't tried a max amount). But I am guessing it had something to do with either the contract timing out or it moving on to the next block before it could be read. Really not sure.